# Using strings from an array, not working to element?

Tags: java, android

Pretty new in java.
Very simple issue here but really don't understand whats the problem...

I have an array with strings.
The array elements are url images.
I have a view element which is changing the images.
What I need is to set the image with an element from the array.

```
imageSwitcher.setImageUrl(Last_images[1].toString());
                Log.d("D1",Last_images[1].toString());
```

In the first line if I give it for example "www.example.com/1.jpg" its working.
However when I give it the array element its not working.
In the log.cat its showing the right url...

In the onCreate I have : Last_images = new String[10];
and in the class values I have : String[] Last_images = null;

Coming from PHP and I'm really confused why it is not working and I really think its something easy.

Comment: There is only a method [ImageSwitcher.setImageURI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29). What is your `imageSwitcher` class?

Comment: Even `Last_images[1]` will do , `toString()` is redundant . What is the issue ? What is the content of `Last_images[1]` ? Pointer, an array with 10 elements will be indexed from 0 to 9.

Comment: Just avoid calling toString when the Object is actually a String.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear from your question . But just some guess

If you are trying to access the first element of array luse `Last_images[0]`. And there is no need to use `toString` method ( no harm either).

If this is not the cases Then I would like to see the codes related to the assignment of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Last_images may be null: in my opionion you should do something like that:

```
 if (Last_images != null && Last_images[i] != null) {
     imageSwitcher.setImageUrl(Last_images[1]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
imageSwitcher.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Last_images[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Documentation, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html, the class ImageSwitcher has a setImageURI(Uri uri) method. To create Uri objects, simply call Uri.parse(String myString).